# Prevent copy of app from overwriting the original

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a windows phone application for an event. The event has an last year's event already had a windows phone application and all I really need to do are some updates. So I made a copy of the old application and started modifying it instead of creating a new solution from scratch.

Now here's my issue: when I deploy the new event application with Visual Studio to my phone it overwrites the old application. This is something I don't want, as I want to be able to compare the two on my phone. I also suspect that this might give me some issues when I upload the application to the store.

I suspect that this has something to do with copying files that are supposed to be unique for each application.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you changed the "Product ID" value in the WMAppManifest.xml?

Comment: @Robert no I haven't, what do I change it to? Just a random ID or do I have to get it from somewhere?

Comment: @Fester Just a random ID. You can use the GUID generator integrated to Visual Studio (in the tools menu)

Comment: I also had to manually change the Package.appxmanifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed this was by generating a GUID id using the GUID generator in Visual Studio ( as suggested by @Robert ). And changing the GUID in the `WMAppManifest.xml` and `Package.appxmanifest` files.

Comment: I know this information can be found in the comments as well but I wanted to answer the question for completeness sake.